# Psexec with pythin syntax issue

Tags: python, cmd, psexec

I'm trying to run psexec to do something basic, but it's showing me the psexec help as if I'm typing in something incorrectly.  Here is the code:

```
import subprocess
import sys

myusername = 'DOMAIN\\myusername123'
mypassword = 'mypassword123'

remote_command = 'echo Hello, World!'
command = '-s ' + f'-u {myusername} -p {mypassword} ' + '-accepteula ' + 'cmd.exe ' + '/c ' + 'echo Hello World'
process = subprocess.Popen(['c:\\pstools\\psexec.exe ', command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = process.communicate()
# Decode the output from bytes to string
output = output.decode('utf-8')
print(f'Output:\n{output}')
```

Here is the output when I run this...

Python Output:

```
C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\pythonstuff>python scratch2.py
Output:

PsExec v2.43 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2023 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

PsExec executes a program on a remote system, where remotely executed console
applications execute interactively.

Usage: psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd]][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-g n][-a n,n,...][-verbose] cmd [arguments]
     -a         Separate processors on which the application can run with
...
...
...
```

Now I can run this manually using psexec from a windows cmd:

Output:

```
C:\pstools>PsExec.exe -s -u DOMAINNAME\myusername123 -p mypassword123 -accepteula cmd.exe /c echo hello world

PsExec v2.43 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2023 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com


hello world
cmd.exe exited on TESTSERVER-2 with error code 0.
```

Comment: When you _aren't_ using `shell=True`, the only spaces inside your data should be literal. `'c:\\pstools\\psexec.exe'`, not `'c:\\pstools\\psexec.exe '`; `['-u', username, '-p', password]`, not `f'-u {myusername} -p {mypassword} '`. And it's generally better practice to avoid using a shell to the utmost extent possible.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just figured this out.  My apologies

```
import subprocess
username = "DOMAINNAME\myusername"
password = "mypassword123"
command = r'C:\pstools\PsExec.exe -s -u {} -p {} -accepteula cmd.exe /c echo hello world'.format(username, password)
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
print(output)
```

Comment: A question for you to answer yourself, to improve this answer's robustness: How is this going to behave if someone has a space in their password? How could you fix that?

Comment: `shell=True` is not needed at all. There should be used `shell=False`. There is no need to call the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) by calling `subprocess.check_output()` to run `%ComSpec% /c C:\pstools\PsExec.exe -s -u username -p password -accepteula cmd.exe /c echo hello world` and __local__ `cmd.exe` calls `CreateProcess` to run `C:\pstools\PsExec.exe -s -u username -p password -accepteula cmd.exe /c echo hello world`.